# How to sum different data in a chr variable using filter?

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I am seeking to manipulate this data into a graph but I want to count the specific amount of `HMO` or `PPO` attributes to the visit amounts (Zero, One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six_Plus). There are a total off 44 HMO and 179 PPO in my df.

| Visit_Amount | Reporting_product | Percent_Avg_Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | HMO | 1.1% |
| Two | HMO | 1.2% |
| Three | HMO | 4.9% |
| Four | HMO | 2% |
| Five | HMO | 10.5% |
| Six | HMO | 79% |
| One | PPO | 1.1% |
| Two | PPO | 1.2% |
| Three | PPO | 2.2% |
| Four | PPO | 2% |
| Five | PPO | 10.5% |
| Six | PPO | 76.6% |

The code I have so far is

```
library (tidyverse)

tidyr::pivot_longer(
      cols = c("Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six_Plus")
    ,names_to = "visit_amount",
    values_to = "value") %>% 
    
  group_by(reporting_product, visit_amount) %>% 
  summarise(n_reporting_product = n()
          , avg_value = mean(value)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(
     n_reporting_product  = as.numeric(sum (reporting_product == "PPO", reporting_product == "HMO"))
     ,percent_avg_value = scales::percent(avg_value, 0.01)) %>% 
    select(visit_amount, reporting_product, avg_value, percent_avg_value)
```

I want to calculate the 'Sum' for how many "PPO' plans  and "HMO" plans are accounted for for each visit amount. For example, are 2 HMO plans contributing to one visit amount?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you add a reproducible sample data set using `dput`?

Answer (score 0):

There is the `count` function:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Visit_Amount, ~Reporting_product, ~Percent_Avg_Value,
          "One",              "HMO",             "1.1%",
          "Two",              "HMO",             "1.2%",
        "Three",              "HMO",             "4.9%",
         "Four",              "HMO",               "2%",
         "Five",              "HMO",            "10.5%",
          "Six",              "HMO",              "79%",
          "One",              "PPO",             "1.1%",
          "Two",              "PPO",             "1.2%",
        "Three",              "PPO",             "2.2%",
         "Four",              "PPO",               "2%",
         "Five",              "PPO",            "10.5%",
          "Six",              "PPO",            "76.6%"
  )
data %>% count(Reporting_product)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   Reporting_product     n
#>   <chr>             <int>
#> 1 HMO                   6
#> 2 PPO                   6
data %>% count(Visit_Amount, Reporting_product)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>    Visit_Amount Reporting_product     n
#>    <chr>        <chr>             <int>
#>  1 Five         HMO                   1
#>  2 Five         PPO                   1
#>  3 Four         HMO                   1
#>  4 Four         PPO                   1
#>  5 One          HMO                   1
#>  6 One          PPO                   1
#>  7 Six          HMO                   1
#>  8 Six          PPO                   1
#>  9 Three        HMO                   1
#> 10 Three        PPO                   1
#> 11 Two          HMO                   1
#> 12 Two          PPO                   1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: The 'df' I am working with is 223 x 8. There are a total of 44 HMO and 179 PPO. I want calculate how many HMO out of the 44 are attributing to each visit amount, the same with PPO.

Comment: 223 columns? Is the table you posted in the example not your example input data? Table dimensions are usually reported in number of rows x number of columns. Then, do `count` after `pivot_longer`